# How can I access to id on SQlite?

Tags: database, flutter, sqlite, dart

I have no idea how can I solve this error

```
class ToDo {
  final int id;
  final String category;
  final String name;
  final int year;
  final int month;
  final int date;
  final int intdone;
  ToDo({required this.id,
    required this.category,
    required this.name,
    required this. year,
    required this. month,
    required this. date,
    required this. intdone,
  });
  }
}
```

```
final String TableName2 = 'ToDoList';
Future<Database> get database2 async {
    if (_db2 != null) return _db2;
    _db2 = openDatabase(
      join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'ToDoList.db'),
      onCreate: (db, version) {
        return db.execute(
          'CREATE TABLE ToDoList(id INTEGER, category TEXT, name TEXT, year INTEGER, month INTEGER, date INTEGER, intdone INTEGER)',
        );
      },
      version: 1,
    );
    return _db2;
  }

Future<void> insertToDo(ToDo todo) async {
    final db = await database2;
    await db.insert(
      TableName2,
      todo.toMap(),
      conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
    );
  }
```

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      child: Icon(Icons.check),
      onPressed: () {
            sd.insertToDo(ToDo(id: 0, category: 'd', name: 'd', year: 2022, month: 10, date: 18, intdone: 0));
                    },
),
```

this code returns error

> E/SQLiteLog(30805): (1) table ToDoList has no column named done in "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ToDoList (id, category, name, year, month, date, done) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
> E/flutter (30805): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(table ToDoList has no column named done (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ToDoList (id, category, name, year, month, date, done) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)) sql 'INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ToDoList (id, category, name, year, month, date, done) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' args [0, d, d, 2022, 10, 18, 0]}

I am making todolist, and I made to add when I press the floatingActionButton.

When I conducted the insertToDo function, it doesn't work.

The error message tells that I didn't make the column id in table ToDoList, but I can't find why.

Comment: please add the toMap() of your ToDo class.

Answer (score 0):

It appears, for whatever reason that `intdone` is being changed to `done` i.e. instead of

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ToDoList (id, category, name, year, month, date, intdone /*<<<<<<<<<<*/) VALUES (....
```

the following is being used:-

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ToDoList (id, category, name, year, month, date, done /*??????????*/) VALUES (....
```

It would appear to be changed when applying the `toMap()` function on the passed Todo as per `todo.toMap(),`.

Comment: ahh sorry I thought `ToMap()` wasn't used at the following code so I erased it to simplify the code I rote. the `ToMap()` function was at the `class ToDo`.

Comment: I found the problem. at `ToDo.ToMap()` Thanks!